# python creating new list using a "template list"

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose i have:

```
x1 = [1, 3, 2, 4]
```

and:

```
x2 = [0, 1, 1, 0]
```

with the same shape

now i want to "put x2 ontop of x1" and sum up all the numbers of x1 corresponding to the numbers of x2

so the end result is:

```
end = [1+4 ,3+2]  # end[0] is the sum of all numbers of x1 where a 0 was in x2
```

this is a naive implementation using list to further clarify the question

```py
store_0 = 0
store_1 = 0
x1 = [1, 3, 4, 2]
x2 = [0, 1, 1, 0]
for value_x1 ,value_x2 in zip(x1 ,x2):
    if value_x2 == 0:
        store_0 += value_x1
    elif value_x2 == 1:
        store_1 += value_x1
```

so my question:
is there is a way to implement this in numpy without
using loops or in general just faster?

Comment: Is it always just a few values?  The numpy expression `x2==1` returns a set of true/false values that can be used to filter other operations.  So, `x1[x2==0].sum()` and `x1[x2==1].sum()` do the two operations you have there.

Comment: thanks but the solution needs to be ableto handle larger arrays with more values

Comment: Not sure why you didn't take @TimRoberts solution. I just tested with 10,000 element arrays and it took less than a second on my laptop.

Comment: i meant the that the range of the x2 array could have a larger range

Comment: was my fault that i didnt say it

Comment: so your saying `x2` could be soomething like ` [0 1 0 2 0  3 ... ]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this particular example (and, in general, for `unique`, `duplicated`, and `groupby` kinds of operations), `pandas` is faster than a pure `numpy` solution:

A `pandas` way, using `Series` (credit: very similar to @mcsoini's answer):

```py
def pd_group_sum(x1, x2):
    return pd.Series(x1, index=x2).groupby(x2).sum()
```

A pure `numpy` way, using `np.unique` and some fancy indexing:

```py
def np_group_sum(a, groups):
    _, ix, rix = np.unique(groups, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)
    return np.where(np.arange(len(ix))[:, None] == rix, a, 0).sum(axis=1)
```

Note: a better pure `numpy` way is inspired by @Woodford's answer:

```py
def selsum(a, g, e):
    return a[g==e].sum()

vselsum = np.vectorize(selsum, signature='(n),(n),()->()')

def np_group_sum2(a, groups):
    return vselsum(a, groups, np.unique(groups))
```

Yet another pure `numpy` way is inspired by a comment from @mapf about using `argsort()`. That in itself already takes 45ms, but we may try something based on `np.argpartition(x2, len(x2)-1)` instead, since that takes only 7.5ms by itself on the benchmark below:

```py
def np_group_sum3(a, groups):
    ix = np.argpartition(groups, len(groups)-1)
    ends = np.nonzero(np.diff(np.r_[groups[ix], groups.max() + 1]))[0]
    return np.diff(np.r_[0, a[ix].cumsum()[ends]])
```

**(Slightly modified) example**

```py
x1 = np.array([1, 3, 2, 4, 8])  # I added a group for sake of generality
x2 = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 7])

>>> pd_group_sum(x1, x2)
0    5
1    5
7    8

>>> np_group_sum(x1, x2)  # and all the np_group_sum() variants
array([5, 5, 8])
```

**Speed**

```py
n = 1_000_000
x1 = np.random.randint(0, 20, n)
x2 = np.random.randint(0, 20, n)

%timeit pd_group_sum(x1, x2)
# 13.9 ms ± 65.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit np_group_sum(x1, x2)
# 171 ms ± 129 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit np_group_sum2(x1, x2)
# 66.7 ms ± 19.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit np_group_sum3(x1, x2)
# 25.6 ms ± 41.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Going via pandas is faster, in part because of [numpy issue 11136](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11136).

Comment: was very confused when pandas was 10x faster than numpy

Comment: but pandas seems to be the best way

Comment: yes; because of the `np.unique()` slowness issue, the other day I went through the pandas code for `.duplicated()` and family. It is quite optimized indeed. In fact, see [my comment](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11136#issuecomment-822000680) at the end of that numpy issue referenced above.

Comment: @PierreD I just wanted to point out that I feel like there is a smart way hidden somwhere using sorting (e.g., `x2inds = np.array(x2).argsort(); x1_sorted = np.array(x1)[x2inds]` or similar) but I didn't manage to find it. Maybe you know a way. Also it would be nice if you include the other approaches mentioned here in your speed comparison! :)

Comment: @mapf: on the "benchmark" above, just `%timeit np.argsort(x2)` already takes 43ms, and `np.unique(x2)` takes 31ms. So any approach built on those will lose against `pandas`. But following that line of thought, I tried a version using `np.argpartition()`, as that takes only 7.5ms. I updated my answer to include a way using that, but it still takes 26ms.

Comment: Thanks! That's very interesting. I never thought `pandas` was that efficient.

Comment: @PierreD thanks again for all the effort you put into solving this problem. After i thought about it a little bit more i came to the idea of just using a normal slow loop in numpy like Tim Roberts and compliling it with numba. The result was another 20x compared to the pandas solution. So i guess this is as fast as it gets without stepping out of python. thanks again :)

Comment: * actually an invreae of x40

Comment: really? what do you get as timing (`%timeit`) on the benchmark I use? What about the `%%time` on the very first run (not `jit` compiled yet)?

Comment: on the benchmark pandas gets 36.2ms and numba 4.6ms

Comment: numba first run around 450ms

Answer (score 5):

```py
>>> x1 = np.array([1, 3, 2, 7])
>>> x2 = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])
>>> for index in np.unique(x2):
>>>     print(f'{index}: {x1[x2==index].sum()}')
0: 8
1: 5
>>> # or in one line
>>> [(index, x1[x2==index].sum()) for index in np.unique(x2)]
[(0, 8), (1, 5)]
```

Comment: Small idea for improvement: I'm not sure, but I guess `set(x2)` would be a bit faster than `np.unique(x2)`.

Comment: i forgot to say that the solution should be able to handle "store" values ,the best thing would be a function that returns an array with the corresponding values.So the x2 could also have a range from 0 to 1000

Comment: @mapf Could be, but depends how numpy implements `unique`. I generally trust numpy to be efficient.

Comment: @user15770670 This code will handle any size arrays and and any number of indices in `x2`. Not sure what else you're asking for.

Comment: with `np.vectorize()`, this is better than my initial pure-numpy answer! Kudos.

Answer (score 3):

Would a pandas one-liner be ok?

```
store_0, store_1 = pd.DataFrame({"x1": x1, "x2": x2}).groupby("x2").x1.sum()
```

Or as a dictionary, for arbitrarily many values in `x2`:

```
pd.DataFrame({"x1": x1, "x2": x2}).groupby("x2").x1.sum().to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{0: 5, 1: 5}
```

Comment: i forgot to say that the solution should be able to handle "store" values ,the best thing would be a function that returns an array with the corresponding values.So the x2 could also have a range from 0 to 1000

Comment: didnt expect that but pandas outperformed numpy by a faktor of 8x!!!

Comment: one of the fastest ways and faster than pure `numpy`. Good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

using compress

```
from itertools import compress
result = [sum(compress(x1,x2)),sum(compress(x1, (map(lambda x: not x,x2))))]
```

Answer (score 1):

This extends your loop into a larger number of values.  I can't think of a numpy one-liner to do this.

```
sums = [0] * 10000
for vx1,vx2 in zip(x1,x2):
    sums[vx2] += vx1
```

Comment: i forgot to say that the solution should be able to handle "store" values ,the best thing would be a function that returns an array with the corresponding values.So the x2 could also have a range from 0 to 1000

Comment: im dumb :(  i think this will do it!

Answer (score 1):

By casting the second list as a Boolean array, you can use it to index the first one:

```py
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([1, 3, 2, 4])
x2 = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0], dtype=bool)

end = [np.sum(x1[~x2]), np.sum(x1[x2])]
end
```

```
[5, 5]
```

**Edit:**
If `x2` can have values larger than 1, you could use a list comprehension:

```py
x1 = np.array([1, 3, 2, 4])
x2 = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])

end = [np.sum(x1[x2 == i]) for i in range(max(x2) + 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This extends the solution Tim Roberts suggested at the begining but will account for `X2` having multiple values i.e Non binary. Here those values are strictly adjacent because the for loop uses the `range` of `rng` but it could be extended so that x2 has values that are not adjacent e.g [0 2 2 2 1 4] <- no 3's whereas `randint` used for this example will return a vector something like [0 1 1 3 4 2].

```
import numpy as np
rng = 5 # Range of values for x2 i.e [0 1 2 3 4]
x1 = np.random.randint(20, size=10000) #random vector of size 10k
x2 = np.random.randint(5, size=10000) # inexing vector size 10k with range (0-4)


store = []
for i in range(rng): # loop and append to list
    store.append(x1[x2==i].sum())
```